# PhoneRTC Signal and Turn servers Vs Asteriks server

Tags: cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, phonertc

**REQUIREMENTS**: I was looking at using PhoneRTC Cordova plugin to broadcast a message from an Android tablet to a speaker/microphone device, where both these devices are in a private network based on an Asteriks server.

So any message from tablet to speaker/microphone device must be routed through the Asteriks server.

**QUESTION**: The Cordova plugin 'PhoneRTC' requires a SIGNAL server as well as a TURN server. In my case there is only an Asteriks server, so what will be the SIGNAL server and TURN server in above sceanrio? Maybe the Asteriks server can act as both the SIGNAL and TURN server, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge is how you can change the PhoneRTC server for another one.
In my case, I would like to use PhoneRTC but I would like to use easyRTC server instead of PhoneRTC server.

Thanks